# The behavior of the classloader in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, classloader

How to understand that

> In a multi-threaded environment you might have type conversion exceptions due to different classloaders

I saw the source code of Spring about this:

```
public static ClassLoader getDefaultClassLoader() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = null;
    try {
        classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (classLoader == null) {
        // No thread context class loader -> use class loader of this class
        classLoader = ClassUtil.class.getClassLoader();
        if (classLoader == null) {
            // getClassLoader() returning null indicates the bootstrap ClassLoader
            try {
                classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {

            }
        }
    }
    return classLoader;
}
```

I don't why they chose Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() to be the first choice?

Someone told me cause the behavior of classloader could be different in multi-thread

To be honest, I can't understand

Comment: Please show a link to the source of that statement as well as any relevant background/context information you can supply

Comment: "Someone told me cause the behavior of classloader could be different in multi-thread" ­— they weren't wrong, but the snippet you cited is extremely confusing. *Multi-classloader* environments are the common source of problems, not multiple threads. Associating different classloaders with different threads rarely causes issues (unless those classloaders themselves are buggy). But having multiple classloaders does cause all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() would be the natural first choice, so that different contexts can reliably set their private classloader overrides. While most often additional classloaders are used for loading classes that are not provided by the lower-level classloaders, another use would be to use specific implementations of some classes in some contexts.

When this is combined with the fact that the type identity of a class contains the classloader that loaded the class, it becomes possible to have two classes of the same (absolute) class name that still are not of the same type.

Comment: Given that there are different classloaders in their respective threads, if they can all load a class called com.test.test (but actually a different class), it is possible that in a multi-threaded environment an unexpected occurrence might occur when another classloader loads the class, and then a type conversion problem occurs.